# Android searchView clear text button listener

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

how I can set a listener into 'clear text' button in searchView (not close). And no, `onQueryTextChange` set to empty does not solve my problem.

Greetings

Comment: `clearTextButton.setOnClickListener { }`

Comment: Ok cool than how to get this clearTextButton from SearchView?

Comment: post ur xml code

Comment: It's default SearchView component. I need to get inside the Clear button which sets text to = ""

Comment: Can you add your menu `xml` where you use `SearchView`?

Comment: If you want the search bar to respond to back/key presses, please take a look at this library https://github.com/searchy2/CustomSearchBar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to get `clearButton` from `SearchView` and set `OnClickListener` like below:

```
ImageView clearButton = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
clearButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if(searchView.getQuery().length() == 0) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
    } else {

        // Do your task here
        searchView.setQuery("", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hax. Android is perfect encapsulation example.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I have an unexpected computer crash. As soon as I fix it, I will try this method immediately :)

Comment: But the idea is great cause close button perform 2 times and it's overwritten in code for 2 behaviours. If I just catch when quert lenght equals 0 that's almost same what clear button does(i just get to know that clear button does not exist - only close exists).

Comment: Yes, there is nothing about clear button. It's close button that act based on content length

Answer (score 0):

if you got a is a `TextInputLayout` with id 'searchInput', then simply:

```
searchInput.setEndIconOnClickListener {
    // Do something
}
```

(If you can't find it, you might have to update your libs)

Doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setEndIconOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)